# Delicious JSON List Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need some help with adding a dynamic list of links from Delicious.com to my site. The idea is to show all the newest links with a certain tag (in this case the tag is "flyfishing").

What I did so far is I put the following link in a script tag in my page header to get a JSON list of links with the matching tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/tag/flyfishing?count=20?callback=getDelicious">
```

The function I wrote called getDelicious is the callback function. Here is the function :

```
function getDelicious(){

$(function() {
        var _el = $("#dynaList");
        var out="<ul>";
        for (var y in Delicious.posts) {
            out+="<li>" + Delicious.posts[y]+"</li>";
        }

        out+="</ul>"; 
        return _el.html(out);
  });

 }
```

Now this doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Is the problem in the way I'm getting the JSON data or is there something wrong with the code I wrote? I'm not sure if I'm accessing the Delicious site correctly. Is the array I'm trying to parse through actually what is being returned by the link in my script tag? I'm not getting any errors in the console so I really have no idea what's wrong.

Any help would be appreciated since I'm pretty new to JQuery and I only just started with Ajax and JSON.

Comment: Are you calling `getDelicious()` anywhere?

Comment: `Now this doesn't seem to work.` in what way is it not working? Are there console errors? Network errors?

Comment: In the callback in the link:script type="text/javascript" src="http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/tag/flyfishing?count=20?callback=getDelicious"

Comment: No console errors or anything else but I'm not getting the links written on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You URL in your `<script>` tag is incorrect. The `callback` param should have an ampersand character (`&`) before it, not a question mark.

```
http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/tag/flyfishing?count=20?callback=getDelicious
                                                          ^
                                                 Must be "&" not "?"
```

Furthermore, with JSONP the result of the request is given as an argument to your callback:

```
function getDelicious(data) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So it should be                                                                                                                                    function getDelicious(Delicious){ ....   Do you know if I have the correct array name given by Delicious?

Comment: I'm thinking the problem must be in the way I'm dealing with the JSON array returned by Delicious. Does anyone have more experience with parsing the JSON data returned by Delicious??